# How to control the searchResultsTableView of a UISearchDisplayController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, customization, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I wonder how to take control over the table view that is used by the `UISearchDisplayController`. You can't overwrite the `searchResultsTableView` property of the `UISearchDisplayController`, because it is a **read-only** property.

I've tried to overlay the `searchResultsTableView` by a custom `UITableView`. That works just once, but as soon as you try a second search, the real `searchResultsTableView` is on top again. (I mean, you type in some text in the `searchBar`, your custom table view is on top and displays the search results, afterwards you press the cancel button. Now, if you repeat this, your custom table won't be displayed and the `searchResultTableView` of the UISearchDisplayController wil be on top).

Of course, you can try it without a `UISearchDisplayController`, but I count on the advantages of this class, I just want to customize the `tableView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `TableViewDataSource` property on the `UISearchDisplayController`, this data source produces the `UITableViewCell`. Implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and you'll have the control over the customization of the tableView in the method : 
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 6):

You cannot set the searchResultsTableView, but you can manipulate it in the appropriate delegate method:

```
-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   tableView.backgroundColor = self.tableView.backgroundColor;
   tableView.separatorColor = self.tableView.separatorColor;
       ...
```

Comment: Thank you Felix, I've already tried this successfully, but that's not what I want to do. I'd really like if I can set my own subclass of UITableView. I don't wanna just manipulate the properties of the searchResultsTableView.

Comment: @burki Did you manage to use your UITableView subclass? I'm having the same problem.