# Search result of UISearchDisplayController has other cell layout and behaviour than searched table

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am using storyboarding. I have an UITableView with one prototype cell. This cell is of style  "subtitle". I have added a segue from the cell to the detailed view. So when the user taps a cell it will open the corresponding editor... That all works great.

Now I added a UISearchDisplayController an a UISearchBar, implemented the delegates. That works very well.

But in the search result table the cells are of style "default" and are not tapable. What do I have to do to get a result table looking and behaving like the "unsearched" table?

Comment: The reason for this is that the UISearchDisplayController creates it's own UITableView, hence, it's creating it with default cells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the problem...

The method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

pulled the cell from the tableView, which is in the result case not the tableView from the storyboard but the resultTableView from the SearchDisplayController.

I now get the cell to display in both cases from the table view in the storyboard and now it works.

Comment: Hi Shingoo - would you mind explaining or showing your code that fixed this problem?

Comment: My View is not a plain tableview. I needed a background image, so the tableview is embedded into a uiview. the view controller has an outlet to the table view. when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called I now get the cell from the tableView outlet so the cell is always derived from the tableview customized in the interface builder.

Answer (score 24):

I would like to contribute for answer #1 this is what I did and it worked for me

in the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

instead of assigning the cell from the parameter tableView

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

assign it directly from the TableView on the view so you have to replace this

```
// UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

with this

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: This helped me. Since all prototype cells are on the "Normal/Original" TableView, not the "Search" TableView, it's a good tip to use self. instead of the parameter passed tableview!

Answer (score 3):

I've been using ios 7.0 and Xcode 5.0. I found that search display controller is using the same tableview layout as the delegate view controller. All you have to do is judge if the current tableview is the delegate view controller's tableview, or the search display controller's tableview. But remember to add the sentence

```
tableView.rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;
```

in the following code snippet:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    tableView.rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;//very important!
    return [self.searchResults count];
}
else
{
    ...
    return ...;
}
}
```

if you forget to implement that sentence, then the row of the table view of search display is only as high as a default row, which makes you think it doesn't look like the "unsearched" table.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193094/how-to-control-the-searchresultstableview-of-a-uisearchdisplaycontroller). It may not work entirely for you, but as I explained, the UISearchDisplayController creates the table view.

Check the documentation and you can get a better understanding of it, but it states:

> You initialize a search display controller with a search bar and a
>   view controller responsible for managing the original content to be
>   searched. When the user starts a search, the search display controller
>   is responsible for superimposing the search interface over the
>   original view controller’s view and showing the search results. The
>   results are displayed in a table view that’s created by the search
>   display controller. In addition to the original view controller, there
>   are logically four other roles. These are typically all played by the
>   same object, often the original view controller itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I debugged my code and yes, the datasource methods are called. The correct cell is also pulled from the storyboard and filled with the correct data but the result table shows the default table cell style... I can't figure out why...

Answer (score 0):

In my case UISearchDisplayController was using right cell type (custom) but height of cell was wrong so I had to use

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method to fix it.